# Which is best to make ebooks from web pages: dotepub or epubpress?

Tags: epub, conversion, creation, website

DotEpub and EpubPress are two extensions to Chrome (and Safari) to produce ebooks from web pages.

EpubPress has the advantage that it can have as input up to 30 web pages and compose them into a single eBook while DotEpub can handle only one at a time.

Can anyone give a list of relative pros and cons of each and a recommendation of one of them or for which uses one can be better than the other?

I would also like to know if any of the two can create epub3.

Comment: Why do need to create epub/epub3s? For your own reading pleasure?

Comment: "which is best" is a subjective question. A better option would be for you to write down specifically what you need from each application, look at which one provides the functionality that you need. If you have specific questions about an app, then ask those if they are not covered in that's app's documentation.